# Removing surrounding noises from voice recording

Tags: speech, denoising, speech-processing

I have a wave file whose frequency spectrum looks like this.

[image]

It contains audio, which I want to keep while removing the rest. The problem is that the surround noise changes, just those distinct voice patterns remain. I marked the voice patterns for clarity:

[image]

What could an algorithm look like / a workflow in adobe audition look like that removes everything but the voice patterns? I think that the main characteristic is the line-shaped form over time. Loudness alone is not enough as the noise is loud aswell.

Here are two samples:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzJ2dx-DH1K8QkNtTmhFcHlVUms/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzJ2dx-DH1K8Qm0wR0lVUENGV2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you possibly get input from 2 mikes, and assume that the voice pattern comes from farther away?  If you can, then subtracting one input from the other gives you the background noise, and lets you focus on the voice of interest?  This is the same principle as noise cancelling headphones, which work well.

Comment: Please refer to this recording.

Comment: I did look at the recording.  You have a single signal, which makes it very, very hard to do anything.  (And even if you do succeed, you will distort the voice quite a bit.)  If you can possibly change what you're given, you can do much better, comparatively easily.

Comment: It is what it is. I want to use this sample. As we can - barely tbh - see the areas of voice as distinct patterns it is feasible. My goal is to get understandable voice, not high quality. In how far can you contribute here, @btilly?

Comment: Is this going to be answered soon? If not, tell me where I can get an answer to this.

Comment: Can you re-post the recording to give people an idea what the noise and the SNR is like? And by the way, it doesn't really help to get impatient ... :)

Comment: @MattL. And by the way, it doesn't change what I do or don't do if you tell me what to do ... :)

Comment: Post updated...

Comment: As I wrote, if this is not going to be answered soon, feel free to point me to another location.

Comment: I am curious, too, about a reply. Don't understand why people downvoted this.

Comment: Are you using Adobe Audition to plot that?  Are you using a version that can do lasso spectral editing?  You could do the filtering by hand to see how difficult/easy it is.  You should use a frequency scale that zooms in on the parts you want, and a window size that shows it better.

Comment: @endolith I did and it does work.

Comment: @Zurechtweiser: So you probably want to do some kind of harmonic detection and pitch tracking, and remove things that aren't constant-pitch with harmonics.  That would remove sibilance, too, though.  So maybe keep noise if it's above some threshold related to the background noise?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the recordings, the SNR is very bad and the noise characteristics are difficult to handle, because the noise is non-stationary. If you have only one microphone signal and nothing else, then the only useful method I can think of is some variant of [spectral subtraction](http://dsp-book.narod.ru/304.pdf). Also have a look at the references in the linked document (above all Ephraim, Malah 1984). One crucial element of the final algorithm will be the noise tracking method which must be able to track the non-stationary noise. It will depend on the application (speech perception by humans, automatic speech recognition, etc.), but your goal should probably not be to remove all the noise, because this will lead to severe distortions of the speech signal. You should rather try to improve the SNR and leave some residual noise in order to increase intelligibility or improve recognition performance.

Comment: Do you know implementations?

Comment: You'll find several implementations on the internet, but I can't recommend any, because the one I know is a proprietary software of a company I used to work for.

Comment: Do you think, https://gist.github.com/shunsukeaihara/4602848 is usable?